# X64DBG Conditional Breakpoint on Specific Opcode?

Tags: assembly, malware, x64dbg, unpacking

Is there any way to break on specific opcode in X64DBG?
For example i want to break on start of a function which is

55   | push ebp

8BEC | mov ebp,esp

can i set a breakpoint like opcode == 0x00EC8B55?
Also is there any way to break only on certain memory range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger/CPU doesn't have a feature to break when it notices a particular opcode byte sequence. Ahead of time, you can scan the memory range you're interested in, then set a software breakpoint on all those particular spots. You can use the 'findall' or 'findasm' scripting command to add a breakpoint, or take some other action for each of those addresses.
There's also a tracing feature that single-steps through the execution. It'll be slower since you're breaking constantly. You can log and filter on that trace.